# React-Native Shadow after upgrading to 0.56

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have upgraded the react-native dependency and have some weird issues with the shadow prop of my views. 
It sets the shadow for every child in a View but not on the actual view where it should be. It occurs only on iOS, android keeps working.

[image: How it should look]

[image: How it should not look]

I have increased the shadowOpacity to know what is really happening, and as described, every item gets a shadow but not the main container.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.taskContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
          <View style={styles.taskContentContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.task.title}</Text>
            <View row spread style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>
              {this.state.profileImgUrl ? (
                <FastImage 
              ...


  taskContainer: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginTop: 11,
    //ios
    shadowOpacity: 0.15,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 0
    },
    //android
    elevation: 2.5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 0,
    marginBottom: 2
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As trying to improve Android performance I have read about overdrawing and so I have tried to reduce it by **not** applying any unnecessary backgroundColors to sub-Views. Because the parent-View has the backgroundColor already set, I reduced overdrawing by that method. Now the problem seems that the new update handles Views with shadows and no (or transparent) backgroundColors descending to their child-Views.

**Solution:**

added `"backgroundColor: "white"` to the taskContainer style.